# android performance tunning?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have made a project to display world weather at current time. In my project I used some animations like layout animation,frame animation etc. Also I have used google's geocoder to find the current location. The application is showing the details fine, still I am having some performance issue. Sometimes it's getting stopped unexpectedly. I m not good in performance tuning. Can you help me regarding this problem, any link or method to check how to make the performance better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provide further information that what you are using in your application for example you are using a geo-coder to get current location so are you using any service?
If you are using service so are you using any Thread inside it or not?

If you need your application to react better performance then you should use the Thread implementation for better UI performance.

I guess you are using a service to get the Location but you have not used the Thread inside it so it may be giving you stopped unexpectedly.

You can see the common coding style and code design from [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)